# Kong won't connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, rhel7

I'm not using Docker.

I've installed PostgreSQL 11 and created a user `kong` that owns a database `kong`.   On the same linux box I've installed Kong, and am trying to get it to connect to the DB using [these instructions](https://docs.konghq.com/install/redhat/?_ga=2.40810210.1574540670.1566848424-998489320.1566848424).

Here's a snippet from kong.conf:

```
database = postgres
pg_host = 127.0.0.1
pg_port = 5432
pg_timeout = 5000
pg_user = kong
pg_password = Passw0rd!
pg_database = kong
```

Also, per [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user/), I've modified pg_hba.conf to include:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Still, when I do:

```
kong migrations bootstrap -c /etc/kong/kong.conf
```

I get:

```
Error: [PostgreSQL error] failed to retrieve server_version_num: FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "kong"
```

I've made sure PostgreSQL has the same password for `kong` that is in the kong.conf.

What am I missing?

Comment: you can try to use 'host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32             md5'

Comment: @c4f4t0r, just tried `md5`. Same result. So I've changed back to `trust` which tells it to not even require a password.

Comment: Your `trust` method is ignored. Some classic reasons: 1) forgetting to reload the postgres service. 2) editing the wrong file 3) having rules above in the file taking precedence (the first match wins)

Comment: @DanielVérité, good notes. I definitely reloaded the service and edited the correct file. However, I didn't know the first match wins. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Two things:

1. At the advice of @DanielVérité, I moved my trust methods to the top on pg_hba.conf. This is because he noted that the first match is what PostgreSQL goes with.
2. In kong.conf, I thought I'd specified `pg_host = 127.0.0.1`, but I'd actually put the host name in there. Changed it back to `127.0.0.1` and it now works.

I hope this helps someone down the road.